# Pygame: bullets sticks to the screen

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

My problem is very simple. The bullets I fire sticks to the screen if I shoot fast. If I shoot slowly, they don't stick. Anyone have an idea how this phenomenon occurs?

#### screenshot of the bullets sticking to the screen

[image: screenshot of the bullets sticking to the screen]

Below I have entered the code. I follow this default game flowchart:

[image: Game flowchart]

I am curious about the origin of the problem. Is it the code or hardware?

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.sprite import Group

# pygame initializing
pygame.init()

#create the screen surface
screen =  pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))

class Color():
    def __init__(self):
        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.white = (255, 255, 255)
        self.red = (255, 0, 0)
        self.green = (0, 255, 0)
        self.green_lambda = (10, 255, 150)
        self.blue = (0, 0, 255)

# set up the colors
color = Color() # make an instance of this class - this makes some colors available

class Spaceship(Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the Spaceship.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor"""
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        width = 22
        height = 32
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color.black)
        self.image.set_colorkey(color.black)

        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, color.green_lambda, [[10,0],[15,22],[20,30],[10,27],[0,30],[5,22]],2)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # As the rect method only take integers we store a
        # This value is only used at the beginning, i.e. before the game loop starts
        self.center_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.center_y = self.rect.centery


class Bullet(Sprite):
    """
        This class represents the bullets.
        It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((8,10))
        self.image.fill(color.red)
        self.image.set_colorkey((color.red))
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, color.green, [1, 0, 5, 8], 2)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = defender.rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = defender.rect.top

    # def function to move the bullets
    def update_pos(self):
        self.rect.y -= bullet_speed


# create spaceship instance
defender = Spaceship()

# create group to store sprites in
all_sprites_list = Group()
all_sprites_list.add(defender)

ship_speed = 0.5
bullet_speed = 3


def run_game():
    m_right = False
    m_left = False
    m_up = False
    m_down = False
    new_bullet = False

    while True:
        """This is the user interaction section"""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    m_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    m_left = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    m_up = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    m_down = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    new_bullet = Bullet()
                    #print(dir(new_bullet))
                    all_sprites_list.add(new_bullet)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    m_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    m_left = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    m_up = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    m_down = False

        """Below is the game logic, which gets input from the user interaction 
        section and more"""
        # Movement of spaceship depending on the flag boolean value and on screen width and height
        if m_right and defender.rect.right < defender.screen_rect.right:
            defender.center_x += ship_speed
        if m_left and defender.rect.left > defender.screen_rect.left:
            defender.center_x -= ship_speed
        if m_up and defender.rect.top > defender.screen_rect.top:
            defender.center_y -= ship_speed
        if m_down and defender.rect.bottom < defender.screen_rect.bottom:
            defender.center_y += ship_speed

        # The cumulative value (which is a float number) for the spaceships movement
        # is given to the spaceship rect variable (which can only be integer) now.
        # This enables fine adjusting of the speed
        defender.rect.centerx = defender.center_x
        defender.rect.centery = defender.center_y
        all_sprites_list.update()
        screen.fill(color.black)
        if new_bullet:
            new_bullet.update_pos()
            # Below the bullets which leaves the screen display are deleted
            if new_bullet.rect.bottom < defender.screen_rect.top:
                all_sprites_list.remove(new_bullet)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        print(all_sprites_list)
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee its a problem in your code ... theres too much here for me to debug it for you though (i guess if you are running on some really really weak hardware it might be that... but its most likely a problem in the code) .. each bullet should probably check its own self if its out of screen bounds ... i dont think the delete is ever firing...

Comment: counting from below in line 5-7, the bullets outside screen is removed. And if I print the variable all_sprites_list, I can see that they are deleted when they leave the screen

Comment: I dont think they do get removed ... unless its only one bullet ... new_bullet becomes the most recent bullet every time i think... that is almost certainly your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of just updating the position of new_bullet

```
    # if new_bullet:
    #     new_bullet.update_pos()
    #     # Below the bullets which leaves the screen display are deleted
    #     if new_bullet.rect.bottom < defender.screen_rect.top:
    #         all_sprites_list.remove(new_bullet)
```

update the position of all bullets

```
    for bullet in all_sprites_list:
        if isinstance(bullet,Bullet):
            bullet.update_pos()
            if bullet.rect.bottom < defender.screen_rect.top:
                all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                del bullet
```

Comment: I tried the above code with the for loop, but it still dosen't work. But now I understand what you said above about the 'most recent bullet'. I will try to get the whole list of bullets updated...

Comment: hmm it worked fine for me ... what do you mean when you say it doesnt work?

Comment: Now it also works for me! Was executing the old version. But now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Joran Beasley's answer is correct. I'd just like to point out that you can also put the behavior of the sprites into their `update` methods which get called automatically when you call `all_sprites_list.update()`. You can actually move most of the code in the while loop to the update methods.

I've got an example with these changes and some more tips in the comments (a quick code review):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.sprite import Group


# I'd just define some global constants for the colors.
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
GREEN_LAMBDA = (10, 255, 150)


class Spaceship(Sprite):
    """This class represents the Spaceship."""
    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Constructor"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        # pygame.SRCALPHA makes the surface transparent.
        self.image = pygame.Surface((22, 32), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.polygon(
            self.image, GREEN_LAMBDA,
            [[10,0],[15,22],[20,30],[10,27],[0,30],[5,22]], 2
        )
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        # You can pass the position as the midbottom argument to `get_rect`.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=self.screen_rect.midbottom)
        self.center_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.center_y = self.rect.centery
        # I've removed the `m_right`, etc. variables and just set the speed
        # of the sprite in the event loop.
        self.max_speed = 3.5
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0

    def update(self):
        # Move the sprite.
        self.center_x += self.speed_x
        self.center_y += self.speed_y
        self.rect.centerx = self.center_x
        self.rect.centery = self.center_y
        # Keep the sprite on the screen.
        if not self.screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.rect.clamp_ip(self.screen_rect)
            self.center_x, self.center_y = self.rect.center


class Bullet(Sprite):
    """This class represents the bullets."""
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((8, 10), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image, GREEN, [1, 0, 5, 8], 2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=pos)
        self.speed = 3  # The speed is now an attribute.

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.speed

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.kill()  # Remove the sprite from all groups.


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Use a clock to limit the frame rate.

    defender = Spaceship(screen)
    all_sprites = Group()  # Changed the name because groups are not lists.
    all_sprites.add(defender)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    defender.speed_x = defender.max_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    defender.speed_x = -defender.max_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    defender.speed_y = -defender.max_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    defender.speed_y = defender.max_speed
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    new_bullet = Bullet(defender.rect.midtop)  # Pass the pos.
                    all_sprites.add(new_bullet)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and defender.speed_x > 0:
                    defender.speed_x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and defender.speed_x < 0:
                    defender.speed_x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and defender.speed_y < 0:
                    defender.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and defender.speed_y > 0:
                    defender.speed_y = 0

        all_sprites.update()  # Calls the update methods of all sprites.

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.

run_game()
```